# how to make a comments system for specific post and retrieve it?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am making question and answer system for a website. I am having an issue here. I want to make users add specific comments for each post. the script I made is similar to Quora.com  so you can understand how my script is working... this is how my comment table looks like please take a look at the pic. **how can I add specific comments for each post ?**

[image: take a look at the image (comments table)]

```
    //code for insert comments to the tables 
    function setComments($connection) {
        if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
            $uid = $_POST['uid'];
            $date = $_POST['date'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            //sql connection 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid,date,message) VALUES ('$uid','$date','$message')";
            $result = $connection ->query($sql);
        }
    }
    //function for get comments from the databse 
    function getComments($connection) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
        $result = $connection ->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //showing records 
            echo '<div id="comment_box">';
            echo $row['uid'].'<br>';
            //echo $row['cid'].'<br>';
            echo nl2br($row['message']).'<br>';
            echo $row['date'];
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
    }
```

I have made two functions here **setComments** is for insert comment

other function is for **getComments**

**UPDATED**

this question table is for ask question so users can ask the questions .

[image: this is question table]

Comment: Well.... you should have one field more in your table, e.g. post_id, so you can retrieve your comments later by post_id?

Comment: hello, @sinisake what kind of data type I should use here int(11) or varchar?

Comment: It depends...do you store post/question id somehow, already? Afaik, int is used usually.

Comment: @sinisake  I have updated the question table also please take a look at the picture

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `post_id` in the comments table, so that each comment is related to a specific post. And declare it as a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

And then both functions `set_comments` and `get_comments`, should have a `post_id` parameter that will be inserted into the comments table and to query those comments for specific post:

```
INSERT INTO comments (uid,date,message, post_id) VALUES ('$uid','$date','$message', '$post_id');
```

After that, using this `post_id` you can query for those comments under specific post by this id.

**Note that:** try to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead for database operations.

---

**Update:**

The column you should add as a foreign key, should have the same exact data type as the column in the original table.

So, suppose you have a questions table, with Id as integer. Then the foreign key column you should add to the comments table should be as following:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD question_id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT fk_question_id FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES questions(id);
```

Comment: hello @Kennard R  , thanks for your answer .  can you tell me what kind of data type do I have to use in this field? I am receiving a SQL error  

ALTER TABLE `comments`  ADD `question_id` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  AFTER `message`,  ADD   PRIMARY KEY  (`question_id`) ;

Comment: @PrinceJay - You are declaring it as a primary key not as a foreign key. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have updated the question table also please take a look at the picture